# Preventing edittextpreference from updating summary for inputtype password

Tags: android, android-preferences, edittextpreference

I want to prevent user from viewing the password entered in `edittextpreference` in the preference summary.I  have handled it logically to not update the summary as follows:

```
    if (!preference.getKey().equals(EMAIL_PWD_KEY)
                        && !preference.getKey().equals(PASSCODE_KEY))
    {
        sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener.onPreferenceChange(preference,PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext())
                                                                                                  .getString(preference.getKey(),
                                                                                                             ""));
    }
```

But when i click on 'OK' button of preference, the summary gets updated. Any idea on preventing it from updating ?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do this by implementing a class called EditTextPreferenceWithSummary which extends EditTextPreference and overriding some methods...

```
public class EditTextPreferenceWithSummary extends EditTextPreference {

    public EditTextPreferenceWithSummary(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public EditTextPreferenceWithSummary(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

   @Override
    protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup parent) {
        updateSummary();
        return super.onCreateView(parent);
    }

    public void updateSummary()
    {
        String value = "";
        int variation = (this.getEditText().getInputType() & InputType.TYPE_MASK_VARIATION);
        Boolean isPassword = ((variation  == InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD)
                            ||(variation  == InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD)
                            ||(variation  == InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_WEB_PASSWORD));

        if (isPassword)
        {
            value = this.getText().replaceAll(".", "*");
        }
        else
        {
            value = this.getText();
        }
        this.setSummary(value);
    }

    private void init() {
        setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
             @Override
             public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                 EditTextPreferenceWithSummary pref = (EditTextPreferenceWithSummary) preference;
                 pref.updateSummary();
                 return true;
             }
        });
    }
}
```

And my preference xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <PreferenceCategory
            android:title="@string/pref_header_database">
            <com.designit.api.preferences.EditTextPreferenceWithSummary
                    android:title="@string/field_database_server_ip"
                    android:defaultValue=""
                    android:summary="Set the IP adress of the server"
                    android:key="server_ip_address" />
            <com.designit.api.preferences.EditTextPreferenceWithSummary
                    android:title="@string/field_database_server_port"
                    android:defaultValue=""
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:summary="Set the port of the server"
                    android:key="server_port" />
            <com.designit.api.preferences.EditTextPreferenceWithSummary
                    android:title="@string/field_database_name"
                    android:defaultValue=""
                    android:summary="Set the database name"
                    android:key="database_name" />
            <com.designit.api.preferences.EditTextPreferenceWithSummary
                    android:title="@string/field_database_user"
                    android:defaultValue=""
                    android:summary="Set the database user"
                    android:key="database_user" />
            <com.designit.api.preferences.EditTextPreferenceWithSummary
                    android:title="@string/field_database_password"
                    android:defaultValue=""
                    android:summary="Set the database password"
                    android:key="database_passwd" 
                    android:inputType="textPassword"/>
    </PreferenceCategory>
```

Hope this helps you.
Cheers.